# Laravel 4 - Display username based on ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a posts and a users table.

In the posts table, i have a posts_author which is the ID of the user from the users table.

Is there an easy way to display the email address of the user, which is in the users table?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

As long as you've set your relationships up it should just be a simple query.

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

Look at the one to many relationships.
(1 User, Multiple posts)
Remember to set the inverse of the relationship up also

Answer (score 0):

If your model has the right [relationships](http://culttt.com/2013/06/10/laravel-4-eloquent-model-relationships/) then should be as simple as `$post->author->email()`.

You must tweak the author relationship because Eloquent assumes the key will be named author_id.

```
// Post

public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Author', 'posts_author');
}


// Author

public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
}
```

Remember to use [eager](http://culttt.com/2013/12/30/eager-loading-laravel-4/) loading in case you are retrieving emails from more than one post object, or you will end up with n+1 queries.

Answer (score 0):

Providing that you've configured the relationships properly, it should be pretty easy.

Post Model:

```
class Post extends Eloquent
{

    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'posts_author');
    }

}
```

Then User Model:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post', 'posts_author');
    }

}
```

Then when loading the post you can do the following.

```
$post = Post::with('author')->find($id);
```

This will tell Eloquent to join on the users table and load the user data at the same time. Now you can just access all of the user information like this:

```
$post->author->username;
$post->author->email;
$post->author->id;
// etc etc
```

Obviously this is just a skeleton, but the assumption is that you have the rest setup.

Comment: Thank you for that ... Is there anywhere i can read more about this? .. The laravel docs dont give much of an indepth howto

Comment: I picked all of this up from the documentation. It's in lots of different sections but mostly it's there. There's relationships: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships then there's the eager/easy loading: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading. Hope that helps.